# How can I have a Delphi XE2 project without unit aliasses?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'd like to compile my XE2 project without unit aliasses but can't get it to work.

I tried the following:

1. `<DCC_UnitAlias />` in the *.dproj
2. `<DCC_UnitAlias>$(DCC_UnitAlias)</DCC_UnitAlias>`
3. `<DCC_UnitAlias>;$(DCC_UnitAlias)</DCC_UnitAlias>`
4. No `DCC_UnitAlias` entry in the *.dproj

These either result in a compiler error
`[DCC Fataler Fehler] F1030 Ungültige Compileranweisung: '-A;Generics.Collections=System.Generics.Collections;...`
(which translates to something like `[DCC Fatal error] F1030 Invalid compiler directive: '-A;Generics.Collections=System.Generics.Collections;...`)

or the inclusion of some default aliasses:
`-AGenerics.Collections=System.Generics.Collections;Generics.Defaults=System.Generics.Defaults;WinTypes=Windows;WinProcs=Windows;DbiTypes=BDE;DbiProcs=BDE;DbiErrs=BDE`

I know this is not a big issue but it somehow annoys me. :-)

FWIW: `<DCC_UnitAlias />` works in D2007.

Comment: Delete the aliases from the project settings dialog in the IDE?

Comment: This results in #4. :-/

Comment: Anyway, I don't really understand the question because I don't speak German. Sorry.

Comment: Ah, sorry for that. Fixed.

Comment: And this is reproducible in a vanilla project right?

Comment: I just created a new VCL project - it showed that behaviour (with no `DCC_UnitAlias` in `NoUnitAliasTest.dproj`).

Comment: No repro here. The default project in XE2 doesn't specify any unit aliases and the .dproj file has no `DCC_UnitAlias` entry. Your problem appears environmental.

Comment: You did it wrong, there is `-NS` switch for getting rid of *dat.wacky.thing*.

Comment: @FreeConsulting Uli isn't trying to specify namespace search path

Comment: @Free: Is there a way to set that option via IDE/for MSBuild?

Comment: @Uli sure there is. But it's not related to your question unless I'm missing the point. You are discussing unit aliases and you want to use none right? Or do you just want to specify name space prefix searches? Which is easy to do from IDE.

Comment: @David, I'm talking about unit aliasses.

Comment: @UliGerhardt, check out "Unit scope names" in library options and project options. I dont know exactly how it gets passed to MSBuild, tho.

Comment: @Uli I give up. Unit aliases and unit scopes are different things.

Comment: I speak of unit aliasses - the `WinTypes=Windows;WinProcs=Windows` thing. I **don't** mean `Windows=Winapi.Windows` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Delphi 10.1, it looks like the default unit aliases are added unconditionnally in the file **$(BDS)\Bin\CodeGear.Common.Targets**. I assume it is similar in XE2 but don't have it installed to check.

```
<UnitAliases>Generics.Collections=System.Generics.Collections;Generics.Defaults=System.Generics.Defaults;WinTypes=Winapi.Windows;WinProcs=Winapi.Windows;DbiTypes=BDE;DbiProcs=BDE;DbiErrs=BDE</UnitAliases>
<UnitAliases Condition="'$(DCC_UnitAlias)'!=''">$(DCC_UnitAlias)$(UnitAliases)</UnitAliases>
```

Removing the first UnitAliases tag should let you specify your defaults more accurately, on a per project basis. Beware of the "DO NOT MODIFY" warning at the top of this file, though.